# MySQL multiple deletes in procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute multiple deletes in one a procedure but only the last is executed.. why?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root2`@`%` PROCEDURE `tableXXX`.`eliminaTodo`()
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM relacionPruebasGrupo;
    DELETE FROM datosPacientes;
    DELETE FROM relacionPruebasGrupoAsignadas;
    DELETE FROM fichasPacientes;
    DELETE FROM pruebaMedicaTipo1;
    DELETE FROM ids;
END
```

Comment: Why are you deleting all rows in the tables?

Comment: 'only the last is executed' - not possible , unless you have FKs on some child tables of these tables, in which case you need to delete the children before the parent. And Gordon is hinting why not just truncate (it's quicker)

Comment: no, any table can be deleted separately, don't have child tables

Comment: @GordonLinoff because I want to empty these tables

Comment: @AlejandroAlis . . . Although you can use `delete`, I find `truncate` to be much more intentional in this case.

Comment: same for truncate, only last query is executed

Comment: @GordonLinoff ... in any case neither works, neither delete nor truncate, only the last is executed.. why?. Im using Dbeaver client.